# How to recover files accidentally deleted from LUKS encrypted device?

Tags: linux, files, gnome, nautilus, deleted-files

I just "Permanently Deleted" two pictures from a folder in my disk that is encrypted with LUKS. I ran `sudo testdisk` and navigated through the menus. It did identify the two now missing files but their entries indicated a size of zero.

Is LUKS designed to wipe the empty space so that deleted files are not recoverable? Or was testdisk not fit for the job? Are there other tools that may help save my photos?

Comment: With encryption that's what happens.

Comment: LUKS doesn't even know about filesystems... it's just block device encryption. Try photorec. But if you didn't switch to readonly immedately it could simply be overwritten already. Or TRIM/discard already removed it, if you're using that and have allow-discards for LUKS enabled.

Comment: Did you try to restore the files from backup? If the files are important you **must** have backup. If you do not have backup seems like the files are not important.